# Respuesta del metodo get de php curl class la devuelve vacia

Tags: php, api, curl

estoy haciedo pruebas con la libreria php-curl-class realizacion peticiones a diferentes endpoints pero me llama la atencion que cuando la hago desde el agente postman si me responde pero desde mi api no responde. Alguien pudiera decirme porque pasa esto.

```
public function nubarium(){
        $response = [];
        if(!isset($this->params[0])){
            http_response_code(404);
            $response   = ["error"=>"true", "code"=>404, "message"=>"resource not fount"];
        }else{
            switch ($this->params[0]) {
                case 'coindesk':
                    $this->curl->get('http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
                    if($this->curl->error) {
                        $response   = ["error"=>"true", "code"=>$this->curl->errorCode, "message"=>$this->curl->errorMessage];
                    }else {
                        $response   = ["error"=>"false", "respusta"=>$this->curl->response, "token"=>$this->getBearerToken()];
                    }
                break;
                case 'pokemon':


                    $this->curl->get('http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/');

                    if($this->curl->error) {
                        $response   = ["error"=>"true", "code"=>$this->curl->errorCode, "message"=>$this->curl->errorMessage];
                    }else {
                        $response   = ["error"=>"false", "respusta"=>''.$this->curl->response, "token"=>$this->getBearerToken(), "headers"=>$this->curl->getResponseHeaders()];
                    }
                break;
                default:
                    http_response_code(404);
                    $response   = ["error"=>"true", "code"=>404, "message"=>"resource not fount"];
                    exit();
                break;
            }       
        }
    
        $this->setResponse($response);
    }
```

inclusive tambien haciendolo de manera sencilla en un script crudo no me responde nada.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$response   = ["error"=>"false", "respusta"=>''.curl_exec($ch), "token"=>$this->getBearerToken(), "headers"=>$this->curl->getResponseHeaders()];
curl_close($ch);
```

Esta Imagen es de cuando realizo la peticion sin con el http unicamente, aqui la respuesta es nula o vacia, si se fijan en el parametro respuesta.

[image: Esta Imagen es de cuando realizo la peticion sin con el http unicamente, aqui la respuesta es nula o vacia, si se fijan en el parametro respuesta.]

Aqui cuando le agrego el https, marca esta respuesta la request
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es porque tu url es `http` y deberia ser `https`, quedando de esta manera `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1");`

Comment: Desde el postman si me deja hacer las request con el http, pero me di cuenta que si no tengo certificado de seguridad instalado no responde nada. En mi caso cuando le agrego me dice que no tengo certificado. 
Gracias por responder!

Comment: No se a que te refieras con tener certificado de seguridad instalado, probé las dos URL que tienes en los ejemplos usando `https` y obtengo los resultados, además de que la API de pokeapi es pública, no se porque usas `http` en vez de usar `https`

Comment: Sería interesante que captures los errores y los muestres para saber por qué falla exactamente o que revises el log de errores.

Comment: Agregue capturas para mostrar la respuesta. No me genero ningun log de error la peticion.

Comment: @BrayanGonzalez las url son diferentes? O porque te da token en la de Pokémon? Y los headers creo que son innecesarios en este caso , podrías compartir los Endpoint, porque probé directamente la de Pokémon y no tuve ningún problema en recibir los datos